# How can I extract contact data from a .vcf file in android?

Tags: android, contacts

When I am sharing a contact from android system contact app as file it is shared as content://com.android.contacts.files/my_cache/name.vcf .. How can I get the contact data like name and number from this uri.

Comment: It is just a plain text file. So what is the problem? Please post an example file.

Comment: Can't read the number of the contact.

Comment: That is no answer. Please post an example file and post your code. We have no idea what you are doing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [vcfTelExtractor module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vcftelextractor) to do this. You can run this on node to parse the numbers. It's customizable if you want to get just numbers, or as an array of objects with other keys (first name, email, etc)

Comment: This module probably works, but is a JavaScript module, so it would only apply for React Native or other JavaScript environments on Android. It's not an applicable answer for Java or Kotlin.

Comment: Yeah, truthful.